# EOF in while jumps out of the scope

Tags: c, scanf

I have the below code which is supposed to read a file line by line and do a `for` on each line but it jumps out of the `while` after first time of running:

```
while (fscanf(f, "%s%*c%d\n", serial, &n) != EOF) {

    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        if (strcmp(serial, listProducts[j].serialID) == 0) {
            listProducts[j].n_items += n;
        } else {
            strcpy(listProducts[i].serialID, serial);
            listProducts[i].n_items = n;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

the input is a file with the below information: a.txt

```
OP001Y100SSID 11 \n
AP003XMCN90ID 10 \n
BP007QRV200ID 19 \n
OP002HJDE28ID 22 \n
CP009QWDGREID 21
```

for debug we just need a txt filr and just run this code snipet in a main function

Comment: Why do you think that the number of successful conversions returned from `fscanf` might ever be equal to `EOF` (which is usually negative)?

Comment: Your `fscanf` format is overly complicated, `"%s %d"` will be just fine (depending on format of input). And you should check that `fscanf` [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value) `2` instead.

Comment: Or better yet, use `fgets` to read a full line, and then use e.g. `sscanf` to parse the line (using the format I shown). By using `fgets` it's also much easier to debug your program because you can see the actual input.

Comment: By the way, what *is* your input? Please show the contents that causes your program to fail. Or enough for us to better understand the possible problem.

Comment: Can you post the source code to the full function?

Comment: input is a txt file like c:// user/ a.txt

Comment: @TobySpeight: `EOF` is a specified return value from `fscanf`.

Comment: @MaryamGhafarinia `serial[]` is too small.  Post its definition.  A [mcve] is even better.

Comment: It is usually better to check the actual number of conversions, e.g. `while (fscanf(f, "%s%d", serial, &n) == 2)` and if you need to disambiguate invalid data from EOF save the return value in a variable, e.g. `while ((retval = fscanf(f, "%s%d", serial, &n)) == 2)`. Note that I also removed the trailing newline from the format string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. Please check if the `\n` is really part of the input and fix or confirm this. How exactly do you detect that "*it jumps out of the while after first time of running*"? (Step through your code in a debugger or add some `printf`s to see what it's doing.)

Comment: You increment `i` on every iteration of the `while` loop, but you don't increase the list size on every iteration. And the `else` clause of the `if` statement needs to be after the `for` loop. The `if` itself needs a `break` statement.

Comment: Note [What is the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of this parsing loop is to update the list of products from the contents of the file.  The `while` loop has problems:

- the `fscanf()` format uses `%s` which is risky as unexpectedly long input may cause a buffer overflow, attempting to write beyond the end of the `serial` destination array.
- comparing the `fscanf()` return value to `EOF` is not reliable: you should instead check the number of successful conversions, which should be `2`.
- the `\n` at the end of the format string matches any white space, it is not a reliable way to test for the end of line.
- the `for` loop attempts to locate the product in the `listProducts` array and add an entry if it was not found. The loop logic is incorrect for this purpose: you always increment `i`.

It is recommended to read the file one full line at a time with `fgets()`, parse the line with `sscanf()` and report any parsing issues.

Here is a modified version:

```
int load_products(struct product *listProducts, int count, FILE *f) {
    char buf[128];
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)) {
        char serial[30];
        int n;
        int j;

        if (sscanf(buf, "%29s%d", serial, &n) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: %s\n", buf);
            continue;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (strcmp(serial, listProducts[j].serialID) == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (j < i) {
            /* product was found: update the count */
            listProducts[j].n_items += n;
        } else {
            /* product was not found: add an entry at the end */
            if (i >= count) {
                fprintf(stderr, "too many products, maximum: %d\n", count);
                break;
            }
            strcpy(listProducts[i].serialID, serial);
            listProducts[i].n_items = n;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```